# Write a batch file to rename files within multiple folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

I am trying to write a batch file to rename many files with a `#` sign in the filename to be replaced with `No.`.

i.e. `*#*.*` to `*No.*.*`
Examples are `GT #3.doc` to `GT No. 3.doc` all files have differing file extensions. i.e. `.txt`, `.doc`, `.docx`, `.xls`, `.dat`, `.mdb`, etc...

Also, these files are not in one folder but are in many folders and sub-folders.

OS is Win 7. I look forward to the help as I am a novice with batch files and there are hundreds of files to be renamed for moving to a cloud solution that does not accept symbols. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot how to use batch few years ago ever since powershell came out. Powershell has an easy way of doing this.

```
$target = "Your Path"
Get-ChildItem -path $target -Recurse -Include *#* | rename-item -NewName { $_.name -replace '#','NO'}
```

-recurse will go through all folders and -include will filter files with # in it and pipe it to rename-item. Rename-item has a replace function that only replaces specified part with whatever you'd like.

Comment: Excellent, that worked perfectly. Thank you! You just saved me hours of work!

Comment: No problem. Anytime you're thinking you need a batch file look into powershell. It is very powerful tool for automating tasks in windows. Please mark the thread as answered if it was what you're looking for.

Comment: Sounds like a great resource, I will be sure to look into it. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

This [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) should do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "ROOT=D:\path\to\root\folder\"
set "PATTERN=*#*.*"
set "SEARCH=#"
set "REPLAC=No. "

for /R "%ROOT%" %%I in ("%PATTERN%") do (
    set "FILENAME=%%~nI"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "FILENAME=!FILENAME:%SEARCH%=%REPLAC%!"
    ren "%%~fI" "!FILENAME!%~xI"
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Thank you! That is awesome. Is there a good resource that you could suggest for learning batch file writing?

Comment: Hm... difficult! [Rob van der Woude's Scripting Pages](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchstart.php) is a good resource, and [SS64 (Command line reference)](http://ss64.com/nt/) is a good reference...

Comment: Thank you, I'll be sure to check those out!

Comment: This is really very interesting but what about a batch file to rename recursively only .exe files? That would be awesome. I need to replace the word "version" with a simple "v" in more than 2k folders, each containing up to 6 subfolders. Thanks in advance for any suggestions :)

Comment: @EtaBeta, you just have to adapt the file pattern: `set "PATTERN=*.exe"`...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks aschipfl :)

You mean like this?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "ROOT=D:\path\to\root\folder\"
set "PATTERN=version.exe"
set "SEARCH=version"
set "REPLAC=v"

for /R "%ROOT%" %%I in ("%PATTERN%") do (
    set "FILENAME=%%~nI"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "FILENAME=!FILENAME:%SEARCH%=%REPLAC%!"
    ren "%%~fI" "!FILENAME!%~xI"
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

And to rename also all folders and all nested subfolders containing the word "version" to change to "v"?