# Renaming file names in all subdirectories

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to rename all files in all folders which are named beginning with the string `p-01-`.

This is short example of the structure of folders and files in the root directory:

```
P-79-23 - 01. PA
P-79-23 - 02-2. PS
P-79-23 - 02. PK
```

P-79-23 - 01. PA dir

```
01. P-79-23 - 01.PA (IDR)
02. P-79-23 - 01.PA (iIDR)
03. P-79-23 - 01.PA (iiIDR)
P-01-23 - 01.PA-TK.docx
P-01-23 - 01.PA.xlsx
P-01-23 - 01.PA-Txt.docx
P-01-23 - 01.PA-txt.xlsx
```

File name change

```
P-01-23 - 01.PA-TK.docx  -->  P-79-23 - 01.PA-TK.docx
```

I'm using a modification of [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126978/write-a-batch-file-to-rename-files-within-multiple-folders/77373895#77373895)

Here is my version:

```batch-file
@echo on
chcp 65001 >NUL
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "ROOT=%~dp0"
set "PATTERN=*p-01-*.*"
set "SEARCH=p-01-"
set "REPLAC=P-99-"

for /R "%ROOT%" %%I in ("%PATTERN%") do (
set "FILENAME=%%~nI"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "FILENAME=!FILENAME:%SEARCH%=%REPLAC%!"
rename "%%~fI" "!FILENAME!%~xI"
endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Script does not do enything. Log output:

```
d:\test>chcp 65001  1>NUL 
d:\test>setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion 
d:\test>rem // Define constants here: 
d:\test>set "ROOT=d:\test\" 
d:\test>set "PATTERN=*p-01-*.*" 
d:\test>set "SEARCH=p-01-" 
d:\test>set "REPLAC=P-99-" 
d:\test>    rename "%~fI" "!FILENAME!!%~xI"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whe you say "all files in all folders", which folders specifically? Please [Edit] your question to include directory structures showing your target and batch file locations, and ideally one showing how you'd like it to be after the script has completed. Whilst you're doing that please ensure that the actual output you are seeing is what you have submitted. Currently I cannot think of a reason why the `for`, `set`, `setlocal`, and `set` commands are not being `echo`ed to the screen.

Comment: Your question is still confusing. First of all the root directory of the current working directory is ```\```, and of `D:` is ```D:\```.  Your batch file however appears to be located in `d:\test`, although that is dubious too because I'd expect the prompt to display as `D:\test>`, not `d:\test>` and `%~dp0` to resolve to ```D:\test\```, not ```d:\test\```. If you want proper help, I'd advise that you do not needleesly change things. For showing your structures there is a `tree` command utility. Please open a Command Prompt, type `tree /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key to learn how it works.

Comment: I'm trying to make a script that will search for all files in all directories starting from location of the somenameofthescript.bat and replace p-01- with p-79-, or maybe p-08- with p-197-, it will depend on situations. In some file names there is number 001 or 01 that should remain 001 and 01, and 02, 03, 04 etc that's why i can not change 01 to 79 or some thing else.

Comment: The output you have submitted appears to have been modified, and does not show what it should either. Please [Edit] your question, and replace the output with genuine paths and unchanged content. Please also replace your structure with the output from the `tree` command, (ran from the batch file location). You can remove some of that content if it is too much, but make sure we have the genuine file and directory names, for that submission.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not programing expert, I'm amateur, but I'm trying.
I still don't know where the error is in the original code, and I'd like to know where I went wrong.
Below is the code that works, it has been changed a lot compared to the initial code, after reading tutorials and other examples.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "start_folder=%~dp0"
set "search=p-88-"
set "replac=p-55-"

for /r "%start_folder%" %%F in (*) do (
set "filename=%%~nxF"
set "fullpath=%%~dpF"

set "newname=!filename:%search%=%replac%!"

if not "!newname!"=="!filename!" (
    ren "!fullpath!!filename!" "!newname!"
)
)

endlocal
```

Code is now working.
You can change 'search' and 'replac' parameters.
I hope this code will be useful to someone.

"Knowledge is not knowledge to know, but knowledge is knowledge to give."